# Find the closest value in multidimensional arrays with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I need to find the closest values from a set multidimensional arrays, here is the example:

```
a = [[a,b,1,2,3],[a,b,5,6,7],[a,b,8,9,10],[c,d,1,2,9],[c,d,1,7,8]]
```

I want to search the value closest to 1.8 from the overall arrays that contain the same elements in the first 2 index. My expected result is this:

```
a = [[a,b,1,2,3],[c,d,1,2,9]]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what "closest to 1.8" means in this context? In what way are the two arrays in your expected result close to 1.8?

Comment: Closest to 1.8 means 2 here, thats why both result contains 2 in the arrays.

Comment: To find all arrays that include 2, you can do `a.select {|x| x.include?(2)}`

Comment: Nope, but I need to find those that are closest to 1.8, because some values can be 1.9 or 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption**

In view of your comment, my understanding is that if:

```
a = [[:a, :b, 2], [:a, :b, 3], [:c, :d, 1], [:c, :d, 4]]
```

and the target value is `1.8`, the desired result is:

```
[[:a, :b, 2]]
```

and not:

```
[[:a, :b, 2], [:c, :d, 1]]
```

as the "closest value" is `2` and

```
[[:c, :d, 1], [:c, :d, 4]].flatten.include?(2) #=> false
```

(At the end, however, I offer a solution for the case where "closest "value" is to be obtained for every group of elements having the same first two elements.)

**Code**

If my assumption is correct, obtaining the desired result is simple:

```
def extract_closest(a, target)
  closest = a.flatten.
              select { |e| e.respond_to?(:abs) }.
              min_by { |e| (e.to_f-target).abs }
  a.select { |e| e.include?(closest) }.uniq { |e| e[0,2] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
target = 1.8

a1 = [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7], [:a, :b, 8, 9, 2],
      [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9], [:c, :d, 1, 7, 8]]
```

(Notice that I've changed the last element of `a1[2]` from the example.)

```
extract_closest(a1, target)
  #=> [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9]]

a2 = [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7], [:a, :b, 8, 9, 2],
      [:c, :d, 1, 3, 9], [:c, :d, 1, 7, 8]]

extract_closest(a2, target)
  #=> [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3]]
```

**Explanation**

For the first example above, the steps are as follows:

```
b = a1.flatten
  #=> [:a, :b, 1, 2, 3, :a, :b, 5, 6, 7, :a, :b, 8, 9, 10,
  #    :c, :d, 1, 2, 9, :c, :d, 1, 7, 8]
c = b.select { |e| e.respond_to?(:-) }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 9, 1, 7, 8] 
closest = c.min_by { |e| (e.to_f-target).abs }
  #=> 2 

enum = a.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7],
  #     [:a, :b, 8, 9, 10], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9], [:c, :d, 1, 7, 8]]
  #     :select> 
e = enum.next
  #=> [:a, :b, 1, 2, 3] 
e.include?(closest) 
  #=>   [:a, :b, 1, 2, 3].include?(2) => true
```

so `[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3]` is selected.

```
e = enum.next
  #=> [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7] 
e.include?(closest) 
  #=>   [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7].include?(2) #=> false
```

so `[:a, :b, 5, 6, 7]` is not select. The remaining elements of `enum` are processed similarly, resulting in a return value of:

```
f = [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, 8, 9, 2], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9]]
```

Lastly, we need only one of the first two elements of `f`, so:

```
f.uniq { |e| e[0,2] }
  #=> [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9]]
```

**Alternative assumption**

If a "closest "value" is to be obtained for every group of elements having the same first two elements. In addition, to respond to your comment, I'll permit any of the elements of each array to be any object:

```
def extract_closest(a, target)
  a.each_with_object({}) do |e,h|
    min_diff = e[2..-1].select { |n| n.respond_to?(:abs) }.
                        map { |n| (n.to_f-target).abs }.min
    h.update(e[0,2]=>[min_diff, e]) do |_,(omin,oe),(nmin,ne)|
      (nmin < omin) ? [nmin, ne] : [omin, oe]
    end
  end.values.map(&:last)
end

target = 1.8

a3 = [[:a, :b, 1, 2, :c], [:a, :b, 5, "c", 7], [:a, :b, 8, 9, [1,2]],
      [:c, :d, 1, 3, {e: 1.8}], [:c, :d, 1, 7, "8"]]

extract_closest(a3, target)
  #=> [[:a, :b, 1, 2, :c], [:c, :d, 1, 3, {:e=>1.8}]]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

**Explanation for alternative assumption**

For the example given:

```
enum0 = a3.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:a, :b, 1, 2, :c], [:a, :b, 5, "c", 7],
  #     [:a, :b, 8, 9, [1, 2]], [:c, :d, 1, 3, {:e=>1.8}],
  #     [:c, :d, 1, 7, "8"]]:each_with_object({})> 
e,h = enum0.next
  #=> [[:a, :b, 1, 2, :c], {}] 
e #=> [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c] 
h #=> {} 
b = e[2..-1].select { |n| n.respond_to?(:abs) }
  #=> [1, 2] 
c = b.map { |n| (n.to_f-target).abs }
  #=> [0.8, 0.2]
min_diff = c.min
  #=> 0.2
h.update(e[0,2]=>[min_diff, e]) do |_,(omin,oe),(nmin,ne)|
  (nmin < omin) ? [nmin, ne] : [omin, oe]
end
  #=> {}.update([:a, :b]=>[0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]])
  #=> {[:a, :b]=>[0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]]}
```

as `{}` does not contain the key `[:a, :b]`, `update`'s block is not called upon. Note that `update` returns the updated value of `h`.

```
e,h = enum0.next
  #=> [[:a, :b, 5, "c", 7],
  #    {[:a, :b]=>[0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]]}] 
b = e[2..-1].select { |n| n.respond_to?(:abs) }
  #=> [5, 7] 
c = b.map { |n| (n.to_f-target).abs }
  #=> [3.2, 5.2] 
min_diff = c.min
  #=> 3.2 
h.update(e[0,2]=>[min_diff, e]) do |_,(omin,oe),(nmin,ne)|
  (nmin < omin) ? [nmin, ne] : [omin, oe]
end
```

`update` first considers:

```
h.update(e[0,2]=>[min_diff, e])
  #=> {[:a, :b]=>[0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]]}.
  #     update([:a, :b]=> [3.2, [:a, :b, 5, "c", 7]])
```

As both hashes being merged are found to have the key `[:a, :b]`, `update`'s block is called upon to determine the value of that key in the merged hash:

```
  # do |_,(0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]), (3.2, [:a, :b, 5, "c", 7])|
  #    (3.2 < 0.2) ? [3.2, [:a, :b, 5, "c", 7]] : [0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]]
  # end
```

As `3.2 < 0.2 #=> false`, the block returns:

```
[0.2, [:a, :b, 1, 2, :c]]
```

for the value of the key `[:a, :b]`; that is, the value is unchanged.

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your detailed explanation. My question is on the alternative assumption. What if my array structure is different, for example, [[:a, :b, :c, 1, 2, 3,:d, :e, 4, 5], [:f, :a, :b, 3, 4, 5,:d, :e, 6, 7]], how can I edit the method to fit? Thanks

Comment: What is the grouping criterion? That is, arrays `a1` and `a2` were considered to be in the same group if `a1[0,2] == a2[0,2]`. Would the two arrays in your example be in the same group? Why?

Comment: No, they will not be in the same group. I understand that they will only be in the same group when the first two elements are equal. In my example, I added other elements(some strings, some numbers) to the array, so the method will not work if the structure in the array is different right?

Comment: In that case you need only change `e[2..-1].min` to `e[2..-1].select { |v| v.repond_to?(:-) }.min`.

Comment: Can you explain more on this line?     (nmin < omin) ? [nmin, ne] : [omin, oe]'and I was trying to figure out why I would receive this error - comparison of Float with String failed

Comment: And if I change `e[2..-1].min` to `e[2..-1].select { |v| v.repond_to?(:-) }.min`, I couldn't get the result of the target I want, for example, `[:a, :b, 10, 11, 31, :c, :d], [:a, :b, 1, 9, 3, :c, :d]` , with target = 10, I would get `[:a, :b, 1, 9, 3, :c, :d]`, but my expected result is `[:a, :b, 10, 11, 31, :c, :d]`

Comment: I generalized the "alternative assumption" code to address to permit non-numeric entries anywhere in the arrays, corrected an error and provided an explanation for that case. Let me know if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, 5, 6, 7], [:a, :b, 8, 9, 10], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9], [:c, :d, 1, 7, 8]]

a.
  group_by {|a, b, *_| [a, b] }.
  map {|_k, v|
    v.min_by {|_, _, *nums|
      nums.map {|num| (1.8 - num).abs }.min }}
# => [[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3], [:c, :d, 1, 2, 9]]
```

1. Group the arrays by their first two elements
2. We are not interested in the keys, so we `map` to `v`
3. We want to find some sort of minimum
4. The criterion is: we want to find the array which contains the element which has the minimal absolute difference from `1.8`, so we only have to consider the minimal distance of the three

Comment: This is beautiful, and your explanation is excellent except for one flaw: the singular form of *criteria* is *criterion*. A *criterium* is "a one-day bicycle race on a circuit road course.". So I learned something today.

Comment: Hmmm. If `[:c, :d, 1, 2, 9]` is replaced with `[:c, :d, 1, 4, 9]` you get the same solution. In that case shouldn't the result be `[[:a, :b, 1, 2, 3]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: This is how I interpret the (admittedly almost incomprehensible) requirements: From each set of arrays whose first two elements are identical, choose the one which has the number closest to 1.8.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the OP's comment above seems to suggest otherwise. It really doesn't matter, as you've given a nice solution for one interpretation. I just posted an answer for the alternative interpretation.